# How to calculate the amplitude variation w.r.t. time of Rayleigh wave in a seismic field?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

To collect the variation of Rayleigh wave and body wave w.r.t. time in a seismic field, so far I've the matrix of of the spatial spectrum $p(\omega)$ got from the equation,
$$
p\left(\omega,\,\vec{k}\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^NC\left(\omega;\vec{r}_i,\,\vec{r}_j\right)\exp\left(-j\vec{k}\left(\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j\right)\right)
$$
Where $k_x, k_y$ are the grid points in k space, $C(w,r)$  cross- spectral densities between the $i-th$ and $j-th$ sensor (here it is a matrix of size ns * ns >no. of seismic sensors), $x$, $y$ are the distances between the sensors ( $n_k$ is the grid density for $k_x, k_y$ ).

I'm worried to find the Rayleigh wave and body wave from the image in $k-space $ of the seismic field. Can anyone provide me the theory/concept/idea to find/calculate the time-variant amplitude of Rayleigh wave  from the seismic field?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to generate the amplitude variation (in $ ms^2/Hz$) of Rayleigh & body wave. So far, I have the data collected from array of seismic sensors (I know the position of the sensors in the $X$ and $Y$ direction, $r_i $and $r_j$), then do the cross-spectral density (csd) at a specific frequency * 2d DFT to obtain the spatial spectra (in $k $−space), P(ω). I didn't get the point on how does the amplitude variation of body waves and Rayleigh waves? Thanks